# Once tasks are finished does Mesos Agent kill the Mesos Executor that was running the tasks or does the Mesos Executor persist to receive new tasks?

Tags: mesos

I'm trying to better understand when Mesos Executors are killed by Mesos Agents once tasks that are running in the Mesos Executors finish.  Does the Mesos Agent automatically kill Mesos Executors if there are no tasks running in the Mesos Executor or will the Mesos Executor run indefinitely, waiting for additional tasks from the scheduler or waiting to be killed by manually (e.g., by an administrator)?

It seems the Mesos Executors will run indefinitely but I'm unsure if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Default Mesos Executor dies when task finishes.

Generally Executor should implement API and specifically `shutdown` method that will be called when executor should terminate.

AFAIK some executors could live longer (e.g. indefinitely) but it depends of how framework is implemented. For example Jenkins executor could be long lived executor that runs Jenkins node on it and is ready to get new tasks.

Comment: Thank you for the information, this is helpful and appreciated.

Comment: If that was helpful please vote up https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote